# Getting the same performance using timeit for pure pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pure pandas function defined like this:

```
def pure_pandas(index):
    if index == 0:
        result = nycflights_flights_df.merge(nycflights_planes_df, how='left',\
    left_on='tailnum', right_on='tailnum')\
    .drop(['type', 'manufacturer','model', 'engines', 'engine'], axis=1)\
    .rename(columns = {'year_x':'year','year_y':'plane_year', 'seats':'plane_seats', \
    'speed':'plane_speed'})

    elif index == 1:
        result = nycflights_flights_df[['carrier', 'tailnum']].drop_duplicates()\
    .merge(nycflights_planes_df, how='inner', left_on='tailnum', right_on='tailnum')\
    .merge(nycflights_airlines_df, how='inner', left_on='carrier', right_on='carrier')\
    .assign(carrier = lambda x: x.pop('carrier'))\
    .sort_values(by=['tailnum','carrier'], ascending=[True,False])\
    .reset_index(drop=True)

    else:
        result = nycflights_flights_df[nycflights_flights_df['origin'] == 'EWR']\
    .merge(nycflights_weather_df[nycflights_weather_df['origin'] == 'EWR']\
    .groupby(['year','month','day'])[['temp', 'humid']]\
    .mean().reset_index()\
    .rename(columns = {'temp':'atemp','humid':'ahumid'}),\
    how='left', on=['year', 'month', 'day'])

    return result
```

Which I call from timeit method like this for various runtimes:

```
Query_Type_list = [Group By & Sort', 'Join', 'Join',\
                   'Join & Group By']

def compare_queries(Query_Type_list, queries, no_of_times):
    
    if no_of_times == 10:
        print('Inside:',no_of_times)
        for i, qtl in zip(range(3),Query_Type_list):
            task = 'Task' + str(i+1)
            index.append(task)
            query_type_ls.append(qtl)

            pure_pandas_time = timeit.timeit(lambda: pure_pandas(i), number=no_of_times)
            pandas_query_time.append(pure_pandas_time)
            # print(pure_pandas_time)

        timeit_df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(index,Query_Type_list,pandas_query_time)),\
                                 columns=['Query No','Query Type','Pure Pandas Time'])
        timeit_df['RUN TIMES'] = '10T'
        timeit_df['Key'] = timeit_df['RUN TIMES'] + timeit_df['Query No']
        return timeit_df
        del timeit_df
    
    elif no_of_times == 50:
        print('Inside:',no_of_times)
        for i, qtl in zip(range(3),Query_Type_list):
            task = 'Task' + str(i+1)
            index.append(task)
            query_type_ls.append(qtl)

            pure_pandas_time = timeit.timeit(lambda: pure_pandas(i), number=no_of_times)
            pandas_query_time.append(pure_pandas_time)
            # print(pure_pandas_time)

        timeit_df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(index,Query_Type_list,pandas_query_time)),\
                                 columns=['Query No','Query Type','Pure Pandas Time'])
        timeit_df['RUN TIMES'] = '50T'
        timeit_df['Key'] = timeit_df['RUN TIMES'] + timeit_df['Query No']
        return timeit_df
        del timeit_df
    else:
        print('Do Nothing:')

# The calls for running 10 and 50 times:
timeit_df_10 = compare_queries(Query_Type_list, 10)

timeit_df_50 = compare_queries(Query_Type_list, 50)
```

When I execute the above code, I am seeing the same results for 10 and 50 runs. If I segregate compare_queries (which is not the ideal way), then I see different results. Even the given code is not properly abstracted as I am checking for no_of_times parameter value in if condition of compare_queries function, I am unable to find the root cause. I dont want to repeat my code snippet for each run separately.

The whole point of doing it for different no_of_times is to check the performance of the same query.